Strange error when rendering to PDF from Rmarkdown
i am trying to render a rmarkdown document into PDF and i am getting an error  message :
! Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition.
<inserted text> \@startpbox {
                             @{}ccc@{}}
l.241 \begin{longtable}[]{@{}ccc@{}}


what is this ?
below it says :
Error: LaTeX failed to compile The_Report_.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See The_Report_.log for more info.
Execution halted

the .log file says the same message.I have visited the site from yihui that suggests and i have updated the library.I do not have restrictions from group policy.So what is it ?


It seems to occur at a table in your document. Would you mind including a reproducible example? (otherwise we're ending at the same point this question was ending in)

i am just using kableextra
